# I have written this query to get the balance from two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have written this query to get the trial balance, from the both tables, but I get only one table value, other table value is null,

```
SELECT    
    GL.AccountId, Ca.Code AS Code, CA.AccountName AS AccountName,
    SUM(CASE GL.DrCr WHEN 2 THEN Amount END) AS Debit,
    SUM(CASE GL.DrCr WHEN 1 THEN Amount END) AS Credit,
    SUM(CASE o.DrOrCr WHEN 2 THEN o.Balance END) AS OpeningDebit,
    SUM(CASE o.DrOrCr WHEN 1 THEN o.Balance END) AS OpeningCredit
FROM     
    GeneralLedgerLine GL 
JOIN
    ClientAccount CA On GL.AccountId = CA.Id
LEFT JOIN
    OpeningBalance o on o.AccountId = CA.Id
WHERE
    CA.ClientId = 1
GROUP BY 
    GL.AccountId, CA.Code, CA.AccountName
```

[image: this is the output]

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `ISNULL()` for the nullable numeric columns. Othwerwise you might see only null when you do aggregation if there is a null values.

```
SELECT   GL.AccountId,Ca.Code as Code,CA.AccountName as AccountName,
         SUM(CASE GL.DrCr WHEN 2 THEN ISNULL(Amount,0) END) AS Debit,
         SUM(CASE GL.DrCr WHEN 1 THEN ISNULL(Amount,0) END) AS Credit,
         SUM(CASE o.DrOrCr WHEN 2 THEN ISNULL(o.Balance,0) END) AS OpeningDebit,
         SUM(CASE o.DrOrCr WHEN 1 THEN ISNULL(o.Balance,0) END) AS OpeningCredit
FROM     GeneralLedgerLine GL 
Join ClientAccount CA On GL.AccountId = CA.Id
Left Join OpeningBalance o on o.AccountId=CA.Id
Where CA.ClientId = 1

GROUP BY GL.AccountId,CA.Code,CA.AccountName
```

Comment: It still show the OpeningDebit and Opening Credit Null, however there is value in Oppening balance table

Comment: exclude CA.ClientId=1 and execute again. If you see result probably there is no OpeningBalance for ClientId=1

Comment: You have a left join with the OpeningBalance table, which means if there are no matching rows where CA.Id=o.AcccountId then for those records the value of o.DrOrCr will be null.

Answer (score 0):

For the records which are left joined, need to add a condition to cater to records which ClietnAccount Ids which are not present in OpeningBalance.AccountId

```
  SELECT   GL.AccountId,Ca.Code as Code,CA.AccountName as AccountName,
           SUM(CASE GL.DrCr WHEN 2 THEN ISNULL(Amount,0) END) AS Debit,
           SUM(CASE GL.DrCr WHEN 1 THEN ISNULL(Amount,0) END) AS Credit,
           SUM(CASE WHEN o.DrOrCr=2 THEN ISNULL(o.Balance,0) 
                    WHEN o.DrOrCr IS NULL then 0 END
               ) AS OpeningDebit,
           SUM(CASE WHEN o.DrOrCr=1 THEN ISNULL(o.Balance,0) 
                    WHEN o.DrOrCr IS NULL then 0 
                END) AS OpeningCredit
      FROM GeneralLedgerLine GL 
      JOIN ClientAccount CA On GL.AccountId = CA.Id
 LEFT JOIN OpeningBalance o on o.AccountId=CA.Id
    WHERE CA.ClientId = 1
    GROUP BY GL.AccountId,CA.Code,CA.AccountName
```

Comment: There is Balance in OppeningBalance Table in balance column  Which DrOrCr 1 means its credit balance but its not picking up with this query, all the OppeningDebit and OpeningCredit Showing 0.00

Comment: The CA.Id for that might be missing in OpeningBalance AccountId